# How to implement a payment gateway in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, payment-gateway

I need to know how to implement a payment gateway in ASP.NET for my billing based project.

Is there one gateway enough to access all the bank account?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would look at some open source solutions that do the same thing. [Nopcommerce](http://www.nopcommerce.com) comes to mind and implements the APIs for a large number of payment providers. Download the code and get digging....